# List of tables is not visible in Hue. Error loading tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, boto3, hiveql

I have two databases in hive for example:
1.student
2.teacher

I have created all the tables in "student database" using "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE..." statement which is pointing to s3 location. I'm able to see the list of tables in Hue.

While in "teacher database" there 20 tables out of which 19 are created using "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE..." statement whereas 1 table is created using boto3. I'm unable to view the table list in Hue as I'm getting following error.[image]
Can someone help me in solving this issue?
Please let me know if you need any more details from my end.

Comment: most cases this is browser issue. Could you pls try from another browser with stable internet connection ?

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy thanks for your reply. I have tried on Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge and I'm getting the same result for all three browser.

Comment: can you fire select * from teachers.xx and see if you are getting result?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get the results for all the 20 tables created. The only issue is I'm getting is error loading tables on the left pane as shown in screenshot.

Comment: can you pls try clearing browser cache and hit refresh?  in my case, this happens if you have too many tables in the list (>5000), internet is poor or connection lost.

Comment: There are total 25 tables out of which 1 is created using boto3. Also there is no issue of internet connection and the problem is being faced by all the developers in the team.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that in 2022 CDP 7 still has this issue for some users (even if they use a different PC with which it's working for another user on that PC). It's not a browser issue. There is a bug with HUE. Beeline works fine for this user. All browsers checked and the issue remains.